# Find a line with certain string then remove it's newline character at the end in bash

Tags: bash, newline

I'm trying to prepare a file for a report. What I have is like this:

```
foo 
bar bar oof 
bar oof 
foo 
bar bar
```

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
foo bar bar oof
bar off
foo bar bar
```

I wanted to search for a string, in this case 'foo', and within the line where the string is found I have to remove the newline.

I did search but I can only find solutions where 'foo' is also removed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with `sed`, for example:

```
$ sed '/^foo$/N;s/\n/ /' file
foo bar bar oof
bar oof
foo bar bar
```

**Explanation**

1. `/^foo$/` find lines containing only `foo`
2. `N` read/append next line of input into pattern space.
3. `s/\n/ /` substitute the `'\n'` with a `space`.

Comment: It worked! I'm new to  'sed' and don't know the use of '^', '$', 'N;s' flags. Thank you.

Comment: Join the club. `sed` is one of the animals you just have to digest slowly. Kind of like eating a whale... take it one bite at a time `:)`

Comment: I realized I need lines containing `foo` whether it's the only string in the line or not. So I replaced `^foo$` with simply `foo`.

Comment: Works for me. Good luck with your scripting (and `sed` and `awk`). There is very little, if anything, that cannot be done on a Linux box between the shell, `awk` and `sed`. Together they are the swiss-army knife of text processing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v search='foo' '$0 ~ search{printf $0; next}1' infile
```

You may use `printf $0 OFS` like below, if your field doesn't have leading space before newline char

```
awk -v search='foo' '$0 ~ search{printf $0 OFS; next}1' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
foo 
bar bar oof 
bar oof 
foo 
bar bar

$ awk -v search='foo' '$0 ~ search{printf $0; next}1' infile
foo bar bar oof 
bar oof 
foo bar bar
```

Explanation:

- `-v search='foo'` - set variable `search`
- `$0 ~ search`  - if lines/record/row contains regexp/pattern/string mentioned in variable
- `{printf $0; next}` - print current record without record separator and go to next line
- `}1` 1 at the end does default operation that is print current record/row.

Comment: I do realize I need the "printf $0 OFS" for space. This works too. Thank you!